# Where to store text files in a Ruby on Rails directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a text file in my Ruby on Rails application that I would like to call in a model. The problem is, I want to follow rails conventions in terms of placing files.

The reason I'm using a `.txt` file is because I have a very large array of words I have to iterate over. This is for a `model validation` and I need to ensure that the input does not contain any of these words.

I could just declare an array, but it would make my models to fat. Therefore, I'd like to read from a file where I place my comma separated array elements.

There are several ideas I have

- Root Directory: I could add the `.txt` file to my root directory directly
- Public Directory: Could store it in `/public`
- Temp Directory: Could store it in `/tmp`
- Lib Directory: Could store it in `/lib`
- Inside Model: Could just store it inside `/app/models/mymodel.rb`

Tried to find a similar answer here, but couldn't find a consensus. Anyways, this is a two part question. How would I read from the file inside the model. Would I do something like

```
file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/textfile.txt")
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I store *.txt and same tmps file in  /lib, but why do u need *.txts ?

Comment: What are you using the text file for? Will it remain part of the project going forward? Why can the info not be put into the domain model i.e. DB?

Comment: I need `.txt` files because I am working with a very large array. I had to add the array elements to a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conventions for storing files. All files can be stored in the public folder. This can vary if you're using Heroku or hostings that do not allow write access on the file system, and obviously you need to write.

Otherwise, you must take into account what is the purpose of this file. It might be a better idea to store files in a database or using rails store systems that are explained here: [session store guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) and here you can find more information about [security](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Comment: Will a file in _public_ be served, if someone is able to guess it's name?

Comment: Yes, is public folder :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are not opening and reading this txt file each time you do a validation. I would suggest writing a rake task that would read the file once, parse the words and store them in a an indexed database column. You could create a model ForbiddenWord with an attribute called 'name' of type string(with index of course). Then you could write a custom validator and use it in MyModel, something like this:

```
class WordConstraintValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if ForbiddenWord.exists?(name: record.name)
      record.errors[:base] << "You can not use the word #{record.name}"
    end
  end
end


class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with WordConstraintValidator
end
```

You can put your custom validator inside /app/models/, I am also assuming you have a name attribute on MyModel class, otherwise change this accordingly. There could be other possible solutions to this problem, this is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Is it bad practice to read directly from the text file for that kind of purpose ? I'll need to use this aswell to do random suggestions using a list of all english words. What are the downsides to reading directly from the file ?

Comment: The problem I have with reading directly from file is that disk IO is slower. There is no problem if you will read the contents of the file once and store the contents of the file in some data structure in memory and then query that data structure, but if you plan to do that on every request it won't scale well.  Maybe checkout Redis. Redis supports many in memory data structures, one of them is lexicographically sorted set. It might be useful for your problem.